# Print class properties using custom function

Tags: php

Its not working. print only name. how can i print all properties? 
i cant find my error. please someone solve it with description.
my code is...

```
 <?php
   class pavel{
     public $name="pavel"; 
     public $age="23";
     public $degree="CSE";
      public function myself_set($a,$b,$c){
        $this->name=$a;
        $this->age=$b;
        $this->degree=$c;
      }

      public function myself_get(){
        return  $this->name."<br />";
        return  $this->age."<br />";
        return  $this->degree."<br />";
      }


   }
   $obj = new pavel();
   $obj->myself_set("parvej","24","BSc");
   echo $obj->myself_get();
   echo $obj->myself_get(); 
   ?>
```

Comment: `return` statement ends the execution of a function/method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function:

```
public function myself_get(){
    return  $this->name."<br />";
    return  $this->age."<br />";
    return  $this->degree."<br />";
}
```

... only the first `return` statement is executed, at which point the function exits back to the caller. So the other `return` statements are "dead code": they will never be executed.

Change to something like:

```
public function myself_get(){
    return  $this->name."<br />".
            $this->age."<br />".
            $this->degree."<br />";
}
```

This will return one string made up of the three values.

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/635087)

Comment: it return only name

Comment: Did you make a mistake? See it run on https://eval.in/635087. It outputs all three values.